# Can i use diverter less intake in design based on MiG-29?

Tags: aerodynamics

Which type of boundary layer diverter has been used in MiG-29?
Also, can I use diverterless inlet in my design that is based on the reference aircraft MiG-29?

Comment: You can use anything you want as long as you justify it. You are engineer, you decide.

Comment: You are right. Can you please tell me what originally have been used in MiG-29?